# Android how to invoke binding adapter without changing view Visibility?

Tags: android, kotlin, binding

I am using a bindingAdapter to set the background of a view based on the `state`.

But the bindingAdapter works only when the view reinflates or the visibility change. Is there any way to invoke the binding without reinflating or changing the visibility?

```
 @BindingAdapter("bgClickable")
fun bgClickable(layout: ConstraintLayout, state: String) {
    when (state) {
       DISCONNECTED -> {
            val outValue = TypedValue()
            layout.context.theme
                .resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground, outValue, true)
            layout.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId)
        }
        else -> {
            layout.background = null
        }
    }
}
```

View

```
.
.
.
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            app:bgClickable="@{viewModel.getCurrentStatus()}"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{()->viewModel.redirectToExplorer()}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.25">
<.../>
```

Answer (score 1):

A common mistake with binding adapter is not to add a `lifecycleOwner` to the binding object and without it  the changes to the underlying live data won't be notified to the binding object. so add the following in the fragment/activity class

```
binding.lifecycleOwner = this
```